# Input definition optional keys

Tags: sails.js

I generated an action with `sails generate action task/update-task`. I now am trying to create an input parameter that should be an object with optional keys:

```
  inputs: {
    fields: {
      type: {
        body: 'string?',
        rruleSetStr: 'string?',
      },
      required: true,
      description: 'All keys are not required, but at least one is'
    },
```

However I keep getting error:

```
 The action `task/update-task` could not be registered.  It looks like a machine definition (actions2), but it could not be used to build an action.
Details: ImplementationError: Sorry, could not interpret "task/update-task.js" because its underlying implementation has a problem:
------------------------------------------------------
• Invalid input definition ("fields").  Unrecognized `type`.  (Must be 'string', 'number', 'boolean', 'json' or 'ref'.  Or set it to a type schema like `[{id:'number', name: {givenName: 'Lisa'}}]`.)
------------------------------------------------------

If you are the maintainer of "task/update-task.js", then you can change its implementation to solve the problem above.  Otherwise, please file a bug report with the maintainer, or fork your own copy and fix that.
 [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help.
    at machineAsAction (C:\Users\Mercurius\Documents\GitHub\Homie-Web\node_modules\machine-as-action\lib\machine-as-action.js:271:28)
    at helpRegisterAction (C:\Users\Mercurius\Documents\GitHub\Homie-Web\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\controller\help-register-action.js:63:27)
    at C:\Users\Mercurius\Documents\GitHub\Homie-Web\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\controller\load-action-modules.js:146:13
```

Does anyone know where the documentation is on how to make optional keys in this? I tried here - http://node-machine.org/spec/machine#inputs - but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Type must be 'string', 'number', 'boolean', 'json' or 'ref' like error say.
So u need set type to 'ref' (object or array), and u can use custom function for validate.

```
inputs: {
        fields: {
            type: 'ref',
            custom: function (data) {
                // some logic
                // example
                if (typeof data.body !== "string") {
                    return false;
                    // or u can use trow Error('Body is not a string')
                }
                return true;
            },
            required: true,
            description: 'All keys are not required, but at least one is'
        }
```

Now input is type object and in custom function `return false` or `trow Error('Some problem')` break validation.

If u use schema type, just remove `?` from your example:

```
inputs: {
        fields: {
            type: {
              body: 'string',
              rruleSetStr: 'string'
            },
            required: true,
            description: 'All keys are not required, but at least one is'
        }
```

This is [Runtime (recursive) type-checking for JavaScript.](https://github.com/node-machine/rttc), please check documentation for writing rules.

Comment: The error also says it can be schema though, like for array of strings it can be `['string']`, is there docs on this schema?

Comment: My answer is edited. I do not have experience with RTTC, just did little test on my local, and works. I still think that first example of my answer is what u rly need.

Comment: Awesome that works! However Im not able to make keys optional, its requiring that I pass in all keys.

Comment: Still struggling with making a key optional when using schema :( Is it not possible?